# if condition fails after rows getting affected in select query c#

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

```
using (SqlCommand command7 = new SqlCommand("select * from table where cokumn2 = 'YES'", conn))
{
    command7.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (SqlDataReader dr = command7.ExecuteReader())
    {
      if (dr.HasRows)
      {
        try
        { MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(); }
        catch (Exception) {}
      }
    }
}
```

Even though the select query has rows affected, it does not enter into if condition, pls help on this

Comment: does it work if you use `dr.Read()` instead? if neither work: I don't think it is returning any rows

Comment: I'm sure it returns rows

Comment: and if `dr.Read()` returns `false`, I'm 100% sure that it doesn't (return rows); this could be for a range of reasons, including (picking the most common) running against the wrong database instance (so the data isn't what you expect), or having a different server configuration than you expect (for example, case sensitivity enabled, and the value is `'yes'`, not `'YES'` - btw: the `bit` type would be a much better choice for a boolean value)

Comment: even dr.Read() fails. database instance is perfect. I've even verified case sensitivity. But still i'm getting error